# Convert 3D array into list of dataframes

Tags: r, arrays, dataframe, dplyr, data.table

Basically, I want to group a 3D array by its columns, transform it into a data frame, and bind to it a new column whose value equals to the sum of all existing columns.

For example, consider the following 3D array

```
> (src <- array(1:8, c(2, 2, 2), dimnames=list(c('X1', 'X2'), c('Y1', 'Y2'), 1:2)))
, , 1

   Y1 Y2
X1  1  3
X2  2  4

, , 2

   Y1 Y2
X1  5  7
X2  6  8
```

I would like to convert it to

```
> (dest <- list(Y1=data.frame(X1=c(1, 5), X2=c(2, 6), Y1=c(1, 5)+c(2, 6)),
                Y2=data.frame(X1=c(3, 7), X2=c(4, 8), Y2=c(3, 7)+c(4, 8))))
$Y1
  X1 X2 Y1
1  1  2  3
2  5  6 11

$Y2
  X1 X2 Y2
1  3  4  7
2  7  8 15
```

I know how to do the transformation for each individual column in the original array, but have no idea how to handle multiple columns simultaneously.

```
> library(dplyr)
> as.data.frame(t(src[, 'Y1', ])) %>% mutate(Y1=X1+X2)
  X1 X2 Y1
1  1  2  3
2  5  6 11
```

Feel free to use base R, `dplyr`, `data.table`, or whatever package you prefer, as long as it's fast enough. In the real-world application, `dim(src)` tend to be something like `c(hundreds, tens, tens of thousands)`.

Answer (score 2):

We could first `apply` `data.frame`-transformation on margin `2` of the transposed array, where we transpose arrays with `aperm()`. Then we proceed similarly with the `colSums`. In order to get the right names `"Y1", "Y2"` we make an interim step listing the columns as data frames. Finally `Map` evaluates both lists (the `X*` and colsums of `Y*`) element by element.

```
dest <- Map(cbind, apply(aperm(src, c(3, 2, 1)), 2, data.frame), 
    {tmp <- data.frame(apply(src, 2, colSums));list(tmp[1], tmp[2])})
dest
# $Y1
#   X1 X2 Y1
# 1  1  2  3
# 2  5  6 11
# 
# $Y2
#   X1 X2 Y2
# 1  3  4  7
# 2  7  8 15
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer! If you look at the example closely, we should `apply` on margin `2`, though. Any idea on how to create a new column with the same name as the data frame itself? I know `names` can extract the names, but I have no idea how to pass them as an argument.

Comment: To make it more expandable to tens of columns, you can do ```split.default(tmp, seq_len(length(tmp)))``` instead of ```list(tmp[1], ...)```. I also looked at keeping it as an array but your method is 1) faster and 2) allows for the third column of each list (or slice) to have a different name.